# How are soyuz spacecraft adapted to 2 people crew?

Tags: iss, soyuz-spacecraft

Since Russia is going to send only 2 people crew to  the ISS for a while, I wonder how will they adapt the spacecraft.

Do they remove the 3rd seat ?
Can they put extra cargo on theses flights ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MS-04 [has been launched with 3 seats](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2017/04/roscosmos-soyuz-ms-04-launch-two-member-crew/). The 3rd seat will be needed when MS-04 returns to Earth with 3 crewmembers (the third is Expedition 51 Commander Peggy Whitson).

For launch, the empty seat on Soyuz MS-04 will be filled by a cargo container.

Comment: Bonus point for a picture of the cargo :)

Comment: The DLR_next Twitter account also posted [some images from the flight](https://twitter.com/DLR_next/status/854957142364872704) where you can see the inside of the capsule. I love these high-tech acceleration indicators (plush dog) :-)